# Converting XSD to Java classes using Castor 1.4.1

Tags: java, xsd, code-generation, castor, castor-jdo

I have been using Castor version 0.9.3 to convert XML schema definitions (XSD) to Java objects by unmarshalling XML to Java objects. Here is how I included Castor 0.9.3 in my project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>castor</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

To generate Java classes from the XSD file, I used the following command:

```
java -cp path-to-castor-jar/castor-0.9.3.jar org.exolab.castor.builder.SourceGenerator -i path-to-xsd-file -package package-name -dest directory-to-store-classes
```

Now, I am planning to update Castor to the latest version, 1.4.1, to leverage any new features and bug fixes. However, upon checking the latest version, I noticed that it doesn't provide a jar file and the org.exolab.castor.builder.SourceGenerator package, which I used for code generation earlier, is missing.

I did find jar files for version 1.2, but the SourceGenerator package is still absent there as well. Hence, I am struggling to find a way to convert my XSD file to Java objects using Castor 1.4.1.

Is there an updated command or a new method available in Castor 1.4.1 for generating Java classes from an XSD file? I am working on a Windows environment. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

"I attempted to use the org.exolab.castor.builder.SourceGenerator class in Castor version 1.4.1, similar to how I used it in version 0.9.3 to generate Java classes from an XSD file. However, I found that this class is no longer available in version 1.4.1. I expected to find an alternative method or command in the latest version to perform the XSD to Java class generation, but couldn't find any clear instructions or methods to do so."

NOTE - I don't have pom file I have to add jars in classpath.

Comment: After version 1.1 they added addition check in  IDResolverImpl so that a validation exception will be thrown if an empty or duplicate ID value is encountered.
Set validation as false.


Unmarshaller unmarshaller = new Unmarshaller(abc.class);
 unmarshaller.setValidation(false);